# MPMoviePlayerController media size and location

Tags: ios5, mpmovieplayercontroller, media

Is there a way to get the frame (i.e. size *and* location) of the media loaded in an `MPMoviePlayerController`? I understand the `naturalSize` property, but I also would like to know the location of the media so I can overlay a `UIView` above the media that doesn't cover the playback controls or the unused space around the media.

Alternatively, is there a way to retrieve the size of the playback controls? I would settle for a `UIView` that covers all of the player except for the controls.

Answer (score 0):

Looking at the header source of MPMoviePlayerController I found:

```
// The view in which the media and playback controls are displayed.
@property(nonatomic, readonly) UIView *view;
```